# How to convert a string (with non-digit place value separators) into an integer?

Tags: python, string, int, type-conversion

```
price = '20,355'
```

This is a python string variable. How do I convert it into an integer variable?

For example:

```
price = 20355
```

Comment: Congratulations new user! Question with no research effort, correct answer given in 2 minutes and the question is not deleted yet. You're lucky this time but usually it's not welcome on SO to ask for a ready made solution without even trying to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my prefered way to convert strings with place-value separators to integers:

```
>>> import locale
>>> price = '20,355'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')  # Or any other appropriate locale.
'English_United Kingdom.1252'
>>> locale.atoi(price)
20355
```

This is better than just replacing commas with empty-strings, because in some locales commas are used as decimal separators, while periods play the part of delimiting the thousands, millions etc.

Comment: That's my locale for example which uses commas as decimal separator. +1 for you.

Comment: That's much more robust +1

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the comma:

```
price = int(price.replace(",", ""))
```